# Is is possible to have two virtual paths for one web application in c# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to have two or multiple virtual paths for one web application in c# asp.net?

e.g. http://localhost/test1/web.aspx and http://localhost/test2/web.aspx

Comment: They would, almost by definition, be *separate* applications.

Answer (score 1):

you can open in iis 2 websites that will use the same files from the same directory but with different URLS.

also you can use the ROUTING module which can read the url and redirect it by string pattern from one to another.

Answer (score 0):

Is IIS, you can create two different virtual sites that map to the same physical directory.  Is this what you want?

Each site will be running its own copy of the web code.